# How to stop loading components in single page applications made in react once the server is terminated?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I have a login container and a student container. If login button is clicked, Student container is loaded. Student component further displays Dashboard. I have used React router to give routes. My problem is that if I terminate the server and reload the page it won't load which is required but if I click any other links in the page instead of reloading, respective components are displayed which I don't want. How can I solve this?

Folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    loggedIn: false,
    username: null,
    password: null,
  }

  loginHandler = (loggedIn, username, password) => {

    console.log("hi");
    this.setState({ loggedIn: loggedIn });
    this.setState({ loggedIn: loggedIn, username: username, password: password });
  }


  render() {

    console.log('hi vidhi');
    console.log(this.state);

    if (this.state.loggedIn) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Route path='/dashboard' component={Student} />
          <Route path='/' exact component={() => <Login loginHandler={this.loginHandler} />} />
        </div>
      )
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div>
          <Route path='/' exact component={() => <Login loginHandler={this.loginHandler} />} />
          <Route path='/dashboard' component={Invalid} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Student.js

```
class Student extends Component{

    drawerList = {'My Profile':'profile', 'News Feed':'news'}

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Layout drawerList={this.drawerList}>
                    <Route path='/dashboard/profile' component={Profile} />
                    <Route path='/dashboard/news' component={News} />
                </Layout>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Login.js

```
class Login extends Component {

  state = {
    loggedIn: false,
    username: '',
    password: '',
  }

  loginHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ loggedIn: true, });
  }

  changeHandler = name => event => {
    let newState = { ...this.state, [name]: event.target.value };
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn) {
      this.props.loginHandler(this.state.loggedIn, this.state.username, this.state.password);
      console.log(this.props);
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }
    return (
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
            <LockOutlinedIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Sign in
          </Typography>
          <form onSubmit={this.loginHandler} className={classes.form} noValidate>
            <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="standard-name"
              label="Name"
              name="name"
              autoComplete="name"
              autoFocus
              onChange={this.changeHandler('username')}
            />
            <TextField
              variant="outlined"
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              name="password"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              id="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
              onChange={this.changeHandler('password')}
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
              label="Remember me"
            />
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={classes.submit}
            >
              Sign In
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <Box mt={5}>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

So if I load the login page and then after terminating the server if I click login it shows me dashboard and all the dashboard links are also working. How can I prevent this?

Any help would be wonderful.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This a tricky part in react to handle, in angular we have canActivate() feature to prevent unauthorised route access. In react so far in my knowledge we have to find our own logic to handle this. I handled this is the app.js file.  I checked if the user data is available, then route to dashboard, if not then route to landing page

Comment: Hey thanks but how to check if user data is available? Are you implying login validations?

Comment: you need to store the login  details in cookies or localstorage and then check it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**HOC**](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), that returns **component wrapper** where you will check the response from the server and represent a different container relative to the successful or failed response.

[Role Based Authorization in React](https://medium.com/better-programming/role-based-authorization-in-react-c70bb7641db4)

[Using Higher Order Components for Authenticated Routing](https://www.codementor.io/sahilmittal/using-higher-order-components-for-authenticated-routing-i1hcp6pc6)

Comment: For HOC, do I need to use redux compulsory?

Comment: No, you don't need. 
HOC (higher-order component) is a function that takes a component and returns a new component.
https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html